# How to add rows to gradingtable default* template in xsim

Tags: tables, exsheets, xsim

First I want to thank all those users that asked questions and/or supplied answers that have been useful to me in my journey learning LaTeX and using it to replace MS Word in editing my chemistry high school exams.

I have been using the Exsheets package by Clemens Niederberger (and his other chemistry packages) to create a template resembling the layout of the Dutch State/Central Exams. However as Expl3 got an update, some parts of Exsheets code became obsolete. A few have been repaired according to instructions found on the Web. But as Exsheets is no longer developped, I started on using its successor Xsim. I want to create the same layout using Xsim as I had with Exsheets. I ran into two problems I can't find answers to. One of those problems concerns adding two rows to the default* template of the gradingtable.

I copied the code from **xsim.definitions.code.tex** and added it to my xsim based document renaming the template to *docent**. I can't figure out how to proceed next to add a row for the *ExerciseProperty(obit)* and for *ExerciseProperty{niveau}*. Compiling the unaltered but renamed template also resulted in an error:

```
lijn 266: Missing number, treated as zero. ...dingtable[template=docent*,type=exercise]
```

So my question is twofold:
    1. How to proceed altering the template docent* to include the two additional rows.
    2. And why does the call to the default* template work, yet the copied renamed version in the document not?

The rather extended MWE's using *Exsheets* or using *Xsim* and screenshots of their PDF results are included below.

The original *Exsheet* layout:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

%----- taal/font pakketten
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[tracking]{microtype}

\usepackage[
    typeface=bookman,
    sanstypeface=tgheros,
    mathtypeface=mathdesign:charter,
    monotypeface=tgcursor,
    textcomp=dontload
    ]{typeface}
\usepackage{totcount}

%----- chemische pakketten -----
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{chemgreek}

%----- opmaak pakketten -----
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{totcount}

%----- layout pakketten -----
\usepackage[text={17.0cm,26cm},top=2.0cm,left=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{snotez}

%----- font en versie selectie -----
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}
\setlist[1]{leftmargin=*,itemsep=-6pt}

%----- chemistry omgeving -----
\selectchemgreekmapping{mathdesign}
\chemsetup{modules=all}
\chemsetup[reactions]{before-tag = reactie \textbf, tag-open = [ , tag-close = ]}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{OT1}{qhv}{m}{n}       % qag is de LaTeX naam van TG Adventor
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{bold}{OT1}{qhv}{bx}{n}    % qhv is de LaTeX naam van TG Heros

%----- nieuwe sectie definiëren voor toetsindeling (examenmodel)-----
\titleformat{\section}{\sffamily\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}{\hspace{-1.7cm}\fcolorbox{black}{black}{\boxframe{0.8cm}{6pt}{0pt}}  \hspace{15pt} Opgave \thesection:~}{}%[\seclabel]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\regtotcounter{section}

%----- layout vragen en antwoorden -----
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \SetQuestionPropertiesX {m}
{ \exsheets_set_question_properties:x {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\secName}{}
\newcommand{\lsection}[1]{\renewcommand*{\secName}{#1}\section{#1}}

\SetupExSheets{
    points/name = pt,
    points/format=\tiny\textit,
    headings = margin-nr,
    headings-format = \normalfont\bfseries,
    section-hook   = \noindent\bfseries Opgave \GetQuestionProperty{section-title}{\CurrentQuestionID}\space ,
    question/pre-body-hook = \SetQuestionPropertiesX{ section-title = \unexpanded\expandafter{\secName} }
}

\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{sec-nr}{default}{
    indent-first = false,
    vscale = 1,
    title-format = \textbf,
    join = {
        main[l,vc]title[l,B](0pt,-30pt) ;
    }
}
\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{margin-nr}{default}{
    runin = true ,
    number-post-code = \space,
    attach = {
        main[l,vc]number[r,vc](0pt,0pt) ;
        main[l,vc]points[r,vc](-0.9cm,0pt)
    } ,
    points-post-code = \hspace{2pt} \small \boxframe{7pt}{7pt}{0pt} ,
}

\RenewQuSolPair
{question}[headings=margin-nr]
{solution}[headings=sec-nr]

\DeclareQuestionProperty{section-title}

\DeclareQuestionProperty{obit}

\DeclareQuestionProperty{niveau}


\begin{document}

%=====================================
%   TOETS
%=====================================

\subsection*{Schoolexamen}

Het schoolexamen bestaat uit {\numberofquestions} vragen verdeeld over \total{section} opgaven. Er zijn {\normalsize \pointssum*} punten te behalen.

%=====================================
%   OPGAVE
%=====================================

\lsection{Introductie: Juist of juist onjuist? \space {\normalfont \textit{\small naar: leerstof}}}
\vspace{-9pt}\hrule\vspace{15pt}

Bij deze opgave moet er een verklaring of uitleg gegeven worden waarom een stelling juist dan wel onjuist is. \textbf{Zonder} die verklaring of uitleg is het antwoord \textit{per definitie} \textbf{fout}! 

\begin{question}{2}
    \SetQuestionProperties{obit=OB}
    \SetQuestionProperties{niveau=HV}
    De covalentie van koolstof is gelijk aan de covalentie van silicium.
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
    \begin{itemize}[label={2 pt}]
        \item Juist, koolstof kan vier bindingen vormen met andere atomen. Silicium staat in dezelfde groep in het Periodiek Systeem en heeft een vergelijkbare atoombouw als koolstof. De covalentie van silicium is gelijk aan die van koolstof.
    \end{itemize}
\end{solution}

\begin{question}{2}
    \SetQuestionProperties{obit=IT}
    \SetQuestionProperties{niveau=HV}
    In de stof salmiak \ch{NH4Cl} komt het ion \ch{NH4\pch[]} voor. Stikstof heeft in dit ion \ch{NH4\pch[]} dezelfde covalentie als koolstof in het molecuul \ch{CH4}.
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
    \begin{itemize}[label={2 pt}]
        \item Juist. Zowel stikstof als koolstof hebben hetzelfde aantal waterstofatomen aan zich gebonden. Beide atomen hebben in deze verbindingen covalentie vier.
    \end{itemize}
\end{solution}

%=====================================
%   OPGAVE
%=====================================

\lsection{Elektronen dansen in esters \space {\normalfont \textit{\small naar: leerstof en Binas}}}
\vspace{-9pt}\hrule\vspace{15pt}

De groepen \ch{-OH} en \ch{-NH2} worden functionele groepen genoemd. Ze bepalen mede hoe de moleculen waarin ze aanwezig zijn, zullen reageren met andere stoffen. Ethanol en ethaanamine lossen goed op in water. Ethaan lost niet in water op.

\begin{question}{2}
    \SetQuestionProperties{obit=OB}
    \SetQuestionProperties{niveau=H}
    Leg op microniveau uit waarom ethaan niet in water zal oplossen en ethanol en ethaanamine wel.
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
    De functionele groepen in ethanol en ethaanamine bevatten polaire atoombindingen en zijn in staat om waterstofbruggen te vormen. Ethaan heeft alleen atoombindingen en kan geen waterstofbruggen met watermoleculen vormen.
    \begin{itemize}[label={1 pt}]
        \item benoemen verschil in polariteit van de atoombindingen in functionele groepen
        \item conclusie over de vorming van waterstofbruggen met water\textbf{moleculen}
    \end{itemize}
\end{solution}

Onderzoekers hebben achterhaald uit welke beginstof - ethanol of ethaanzuur - het zuurstofatoom tussen de beide C-ketens afkomstig is. Dat hebben ze gedaan door elk van de beginstoffen te labelen met het zuurstofisotoop \isotope{18,O}.

\begin{question}{2}
    \SetQuestionProperties{obit=OB}
    \SetQuestionProperties{niveau=H}
    Leg uit wat de verschillen zijn tussen het zuurstofisotoop \isotope{18,O} en een 'gewoon' zuurstofatoom.\\
    Maak hierbij gebruik van BINAS tabel 25A of ScienceData tabel <x>.
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
    Verschil 1: Het zuurstofisotoop \isotope{18,O} verschilt in massagetal van het 'gewone' zuurstofatoom \isotope{O}, omdat het twee neutronen meer in de kern heeft.
    Verschil 2: 'Gewoon' zuurstof \isotope{O} komt meer dan 99\% in de natuur voor tegen \isotope{18,O} ongeveer 0,20\%.
    \begin{itemize}[label={1 pt}]
        \item \isotope{18,O} heeft twee neutronen meer in de kern / \isotope{18,O} heeft dus een groter massagetal
        \item \isotope{O} komt meer dan 99\% voor / \isotope{18,O} komt slechts 0,20\% in de natuur voor
    \end{itemize}
\end{solution}


\vfill
\flushright{\textbf{\large Einde van de toets}}\flushleft

\begin{tiny}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|*{\numberofquestions}{c|}c|} \hline
            Vraag & \ForEachQuestion{\QuestionNumber{#1}\iflastquestion{}{&}} & Totaal \\ \hline
            Type & \ForEachQuestion{\GetQuestionProperty{obit}{#1}\iflastquestion{}{&}} & \\ \hline
            Punten & \ForEachQuestion{\GetQuestionProperty{points}{#1}\iflastquestion{}{&}} & \pointssum* \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{tiny}

%=====================================
%   CORRECTIE
%=====================================
\setcounter{page}{1}

\subsection*{Correctiemodel}

\printsolutions


\begin{tiny}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|*{\numberofquestions}{c|}c|} \hline
            Vraag & \ForEachQuestion{\QuestionNumber{#1}\iflastquestion{}{&}} & Totaal \\ \hline
            Type & \ForEachQuestion{\GetQuestionProperty{obit}{#1}\iflastquestion{}{&}} & \\ \hline
            Niveau & \ForEachQuestion{\GetQuestionProperty{niveau}{#1}\iflastquestion{}{&}} & \\ \hline
            Punten & \ForEachQuestion{\GetQuestionProperty{points}{#1}\iflastquestion{}{&}} & \pointssum* \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{tiny}

\end{document}
```

Screenshot of the two pages in the Exsheet MWE:
[image]

The version using *Xsim* including the double table is next:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

%----- taal/font pakketten
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[tracking]{microtype}

\usepackage[
    typeface=bookman,
    sanstypeface=tgheros,
    mathtypeface=mathdesign:charter,
    monotypeface=tgcursor,
    textcomp=dontload
    ]{typeface}

%----- chemische pakketten -----
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{chemgreek}

%----- opmaak pakketten -----
\usepackage{xsim}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{totcount}

%----- layout pakketten -----
\usepackage[text={17.0cm,26cm},top=2.0cm,left=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{snotez}

\usepackage{tcolorbox,needspace}

%----- font en versie selectie -----
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}
\setlist[1]{leftmargin=*,itemsep=-6pt}

%----- chemistry omgeving -----
\selectchemgreekmapping{mathdesign}
\chemsetup{modules=all}
\chemsetup[reactions]{before-tag = reactie \textbf, tag-open = [ , tag-close = ]}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{OT1}{qhv}{m}{n}       % qag is de LaTeX naam van TG Adventor
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{bold}{OT1}{qhv}{bx}{n}    % qhv is de LaTeX naam van TG Heros

%----- nieuwe sectie definiëren voor toetsindeling (examenmodel)-----
\titleformat{\section}{\sffamily\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}{\hspace{-1.7cm}\fcolorbox{black}{black}{\boxframe{0.8cm}{6pt}{0pt}}  \hspace{15pt} Opgave \thesection:~}{}%[\seclabel]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\regtotcounter{section}

\newcommand{\secName}{}
\newcommand{\lsection}[1]{\renewcommand*{\secName}{#1}\section{#1}}

%----- layout vragen en antwoorden -----
\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{se-toets}
{%
    \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
%   \Needspace*{2\baselineskip}
    \noindent
    \IfExercisePropertySetT{subtitle}
    { \textit{\GetExerciseProperty{subtitle}} \\} %
    \IfInsideSolutionTF{%
        \reversemarginpar \marginnote {%
            \textbf{\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}
        }}%
        {%
        \reversemarginpar \marginnote {%
            \IfExercisePropertySetT{points}
            {\textit{\tiny \GetExerciseProperty{points} pt}} %
            \small \boxframe{7pt}{7pt}{0pt} \hfill
            \textbf{\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}%
        }%
    }%
}
{}


\DeclareExerciseProperty{section-title}

\DeclareExerciseProperty{obit}

\DeclareExerciseProperty{niveau}

\xsimsetup{
    path = auxtexfile,
    exercise/template = se-toets,
    solution/template = se-toets,
    exercise/name = vraag,
    exercise/pre-hook = \SetExerciseProperty{section-title}{\secName},
    solution/pre-hook  = \noindent\bfseries{ Opgave \GetExerciseProperty{section-title}} \normalfont \\,
    }
\renewcommand*\theexercise{\arabic{exercise}.}

% adapted copy of default* template in xsim.definitions.code.tex
\DeclareExerciseTableTemplate{docent*}
{
    \XSIMputright \ExerciseTableCode
    {
        \toprule
        \XSIMifblankTF {\ExerciseType}
        {}
        { \XSIMmixedcase { \GetExerciseParameter {exercise-name} } }
        &
    }
    \ForEachUsedExerciseByType
    {
        \XSIMifeqTF {#1} { \ExerciseTableType {#1} }
        {
            \XSIMifblankTF { \ExerciseType }
            {
                \XSIMputright \ExerciseTableCode
                {
                    \XSIMmixedcase
                    { \ExerciseParameterGet {#1} {exercise-name} ~ }
                }
            }
            {}
            \XSIMputright \ExerciseTableCode { #3 & }
        }
        {}
    }
    \XSIMputright \ExerciseTableCode
    {
        \XSIMtranslate {total} \\
        \midrule \XSIMmixedcase { \XSIMtranslate {points} } &
    }
    \ForEachUsedExerciseByType
    {
        \XSIMifeqTF {#1} { \ExerciseTableType {#1} }
        {
            \XSIMputright \ExerciseTableCode
            { \XSIMifblankTF {#5} {\printgoal{0}} {\printgoal{#5}} & }
        }
        {}
    }
    \XSIMputright \ExerciseTableCode
    {
        \XSIMifblankTF {\ExerciseType}
        { \TotalExerciseGoal {points} {} {} }
        { \TotalExerciseTypeGoal {\ExerciseType} {points} {} {} }
        \\ \midrule
        \XSIMtranslate {reached} &
    }
    \ForEachUsedExerciseByType
    {
        \XSIMifeqTF {#1} { \ExerciseTableType {#1} }
        { \XSIMputright \ExerciseTableCode {&} }
        {}
    }
    \XSIMputright \ExerciseTableCode { \\ \bottomrule }
    \def\numberofcolumns{
        \XSIMifblankTF {\ExerciseType}
        {\numberofusedexercises}
        {\csname numberof \ExerciseType s\endcsname}
    }
    \XSIMifeqF{\numberofcolumns}{0}
    {
        \begin {tabular} {l*{\numberofcolumns}{c}c}
        \ExerciseTableCode
        \end {tabular}
    }
}


\begin{document}

%=====================================
%   TOETS
%=====================================

\subsection*{Schoolexamen}

Het schoolexamen bestaat uit \numberofexercises vragen verdeeld over \total{section} opgaven. Er zijn \printtotalpoints punten te behalen.

%=====================================
%   OPGAVE
%=====================================

\lsection{Introductie: Juist of juist onjuist? \space {\normalfont \textit{\small naar: leerstof}}}
\vspace{-9pt}\hrule\vspace{15pt}

Bij deze opgave moet er een verklaring of uitleg gegeven worden waarom een stelling juist dan wel onjuist is. \textbf{Zonder} die verklaring of uitleg is het antwoord \textit{per definitie} \textbf{fout}! 

\begin{exercise}[points=2,obit=OB,niveau=H]
    De covalentie van koolstof is gelijk aan de covalentie van silicium.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
    \begin{itemize}[label={2 pt}]
    \item Juist, koolstof kan vier bindingen vormen met andere atomen. Silicium staat in dezelfde groep in het Periodiek Systeem en heeft een vergelijkbare atoombouw als koolstof. De covalentie van silicium is gelijk aan die van koolstof.
\end{itemize}

\end{solution}

\begin{exercise}[points=3,obit=IT,niveau=HV]
    In de stof salmiak \ch{NH4Cl} komt het ion \ch{NH4\pch[]} voor. Stikstof heeft in dit ion \ch{NH4\pch[]} dezelfde covalentie als koolstof in het molecuul \ch{CH4}.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
    \begin{itemize}[label={2 pt}]
    \item Juist. Zowel stikstof als koolstof hebben hetzelfde aantal waterstofatomen aan zich gebonden. Beide atomen hebben in deze verbindingen covalentie vier.
\end{itemize}
\end{solution}

%=====================================
%   OPGAVE
%=====================================

\lsection{Elektronen dansen in esters \space {\normalfont \textit{\small naar: leerstof en Binas}}}
\vspace{-9pt}\hrule\vspace{15pt}

De groepen \ch{-OH} en \ch{-NH2} worden functionele groepen genoemd. Ze bepalen mede hoe de moleculen waarin ze aanwezig zijn, zullen reageren met andere stoffen. Ethanol en ethaanamine lossen goed op in water. Ethaan lost niet in water op.

\begin{exercise}[points=2,obit=OB.niveau=H]
    Leg op microniveau uit waarom ethaan niet in water zal oplossen en ethanol en ethaanamine wel.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
    De functionele groepen in ethanol en ethaanamine bevatten polaire atoombindingen en zijn in staat om waterstofbruggen te vormen. Ethaan heeft alleen atoombindingen en kan geen waterstofbruggen met watermoleculen vormen.
    \begin{itemize}[label={1 pt}]
        \item benoemen verschil in polariteit van de atoombindingen in functionele groepen
        \item conclusie over de vorming van waterstofbruggen met water\textbf{moleculen}
    \end{itemize}
\end{solution}

Onderzoekers hebben achterhaald uit welke beginstof - ethanol of ethaanzuur - het zuurstofatoom tussen de beide C-ketens afkomstig is. Dat hebben ze gedaan door elk van de beginstoffen te labelen met het zuurstofisotoop \isotope{18,O}.

\begin{exercise}[points=2,obit=OB,niveau=H]
    Leg uit wat de verschillen zijn tussen het zuurstofisotoop \isotope{18,O} en een 'gewoon' zuurstofatoom.\\
    Maak hierbij gebruik van BINAS tabel 25A of ScienceData tabel <x>.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
    Verschil 1: Het zuurstofisotoop \isotope{18,O} verschilt in massagetal van het 'gewone' zuurstofatoom \isotope{O}, omdat het twee neutronen meer in de kern heeft.
    Verschil 2: 'Gewoon' zuurstof \isotope{O} komt meer dan 99\% in de natuur voor tegen \isotope{18,O} ongeveer 0,20\%.
    \begin{itemize}[label={1 pt}]
        \item \isotope{18,O} heeft twee neutronen meer in de kern / \isotope{18,O} heeft dus een groter massagetal
        \item \isotope{O} komt meer dan 99\% voor / \isotope{18,O} komt slechts 0,20\% in de natuur voor
    \end{itemize}
\end{solution}

\vfill
\flushright{\textbf{\large Einde van de toets}}\flushleft

\begin{tiny}
    \begin{center}
        \gradingtable[template=default*,type=exercise]
    \end{center}
\end{tiny}

\pagebreak

%=====================================
%   CORRECTIE
%=====================================
\setcounter{page}{1}

\subsection*{Correctiemodel}

\printsolutions

\begin{tiny}
    \begin{center}
        \gradingtable[template=default*,type=exercise]
    \end{center}
\end{tiny}

\begin{tiny}
    \begin{center}
        \gradingtable[template=docent*,type=exercise]
    \end{center}
\end{tiny}

\end{document}
```

And the screenshot of the resulting PDF pages is:
[image]

I am using TexStudio 2.12.14 and MiKTeX 2.9.7015 on a computer running MS Windows 7 Pro 64bit . All packages have been updated to their latest releases.

Comment: The second question most likely is: in expl3 spaces are ignored but in a document they are not, so simply compying the code is bound to produce errors if one doesn't take care of spaces (most of the one after `numberof`).

Comment: Do you want the `xsim` table to look like the one in your exsheets example?

Comment: @clemens - Sorry to react so late to your questions. Yes, i would like to be able to add a table to my exams written using xsim in the same way as I could do in exsheets. Essentially I want to tag (or provide a property) questions with four qualifiers (tags?): obit - what type of learning is involved / niveau - what lvl of education is nessecary / cse - taken in SE (school exam) or CE (central exam) / domein - which domain in the state chemistry syllabus does this question refer to.

Comment: @clemens - I did some testing on defining the table. The command \ForEachUsedExerciseByType{%
 { \noindent \XSIMmixedcase{\ExerciseParameterGet{#1}{exercise-name}}~#3: #5~punten \hspace{1cm} \ExercisePropertyGet{exercise}{#2}{obit} \hspace{1cm} \ExercisePropertyGet{exercise}{#2}{niveau} \\ }%
 }
works fine as such, but when placed in a table environment (I prefer to use the ctable package) it gets messy. The Exercise ID seems to be stuck on the final ID in filling the rows of a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep in mind that the default code a) is written in an expl3 environment where spaces are ignored and b) needs to test for different cases depending in user input.

In your case you can build a simplified version of the grading table template which completely rebuilds the tables displayed of your `exsheets` example.

The following code does exactly that. Please note that the centering part and the font size have been added to the template:

```
\newif\ifstudent
\DeclareExerciseTableTemplate{student*}{%
  \studenttrue
  \UseExerciseTemplate{table}{docent*}%
}
\DeclareExerciseTableTemplate{docent*}{%
  \XSIMputright\ExerciseTableCode{\hline Vraag & }%
  \ForEachUsedExerciseByType{\XSIMputright\ExerciseTableCode{#3&}}%
  \XSIMputright\ExerciseTableCode{ Totaal \\ \hline Type & }%
  \ForEachUsedExerciseByType{\XSIMputright\ExerciseTableCode{\ExercisePropertyGet{#1}{#2}{obit}&}}%
  \ifstudent\else
    \XSIMputright\ExerciseTableCode{ \\ \hline Niveau & }%
    \ForEachUsedExerciseByType{\XSIMputright\ExerciseTableCode{\ExercisePropertyGet{#1}{#2}{niveau}&}}%
  \fi
  \XSIMputright\ExerciseTableCode{ \\ \hline Punten & }%
  \ForEachUsedExerciseByType{\XSIMputright\ExerciseTableCode{\XSIMifblankTF{#5}{\printgoal{0}}{\printgoal{#5}}&}}%
  \XSIMputright\ExerciseTableCode{%
    \XSIMifblankTF{\ExerciseType}
      {\TotalExerciseGoal{points}{}{}}
      {\TotalExerciseTypeGoal{\ExerciseType}{points}{}{}}%
    \\ \hline
  }%
  \def\numberofcolumns{%
    \XSIMifblankTF{\ExerciseType}
      {\numberofusedexercises}
      {\csname numberof\ExerciseType s\endcsname}%
  }%
  \XSIMifeqF{\numberofcolumns}{0}{%
    \begin{center}
      \tiny
      \begin{tabular}{|l|*{\numberofcolumns}{c|}c|}
        \ExerciseTableCode
      \end{tabular}
    \end{center}%
  }%
}
```

The complete code now calls `\gradingtable[template=student*]` on the first page

[image]

and `\gradingtable[template=docent*]` on the second.

[image]

---

The complete code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

%----- taal/font pakketten
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[tracking]{microtype}

\usepackage[
    typeface=bookman,
    sanstypeface=tgheros,
    mathtypeface=mathdesign:charter,
    monotypeface=tgcursor,
    textcomp=dontload
    ]{typeface}

%----- chemische pakketten -----
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{chemgreek}

%----- opmaak pakketten -----
\usepackage{xsim}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{totcount}

%----- layout pakketten -----
\usepackage[text={17.0cm,26cm},top=2.0cm,left=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{snotez}

\usepackage{tcolorbox,needspace}

%----- font en versie selectie -----
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}
\setlist[1]{leftmargin=*,itemsep=-6pt}

%----- chemistry omgeving -----
\selectchemgreekmapping{mathdesign}
\chemsetup[reactions]{before-tag = reactie \textbf, tag-open = [ , tag-close = ]}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{OT1}{qhv}{m}{n}       % qag is de LaTeX naam van TG Adventor
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{bold}{OT1}{qhv}{bx}{n}    % qhv is de LaTeX naam van TG Heros

%----- nieuwe sectie definiëren voor toetsindeling (examenmodel)-----
\titleformat{\section}{\sffamily\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}{\hspace{-1.7cm}\fcolorbox{black}{black}{\boxframe{0.8cm}{6pt}{0pt}}  \hspace{15pt} Opgave \thesection:~}{}%[\seclabel]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\regtotcounter{section}

\newcommand{\secName}{}
\newcommand{\lsection}[1]{\renewcommand*{\secName}{#1}\section{#1}}

%----- layout vragen en antwoorden -----
\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{se-toets}
{%
    \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
%   \Needspace*{2\baselineskip}
    \noindent
    \IfExercisePropertySetT{subtitle}
    { \textit{\GetExerciseProperty{subtitle}} \\} %
    \IfInsideSolutionTF{%
        \reversemarginpar \marginnote {%
            \textbf{\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}
        }}%
        {%
        \reversemarginpar \marginnote {%
            \IfExercisePropertySetT{points}
            {\textit{\tiny \GetExerciseProperty{points} pt}} %
            \small \boxframe{7pt}{7pt}{0pt} \hfill
            \textbf{\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}%
        }%
    }%
}
{}


\DeclareExerciseProperty{section-title}

\DeclareExerciseProperty{obit}

\DeclareExerciseProperty{niveau}

\xsimsetup{
    path = auxtexfile,
    exercise/template = se-toets,
    solution/template = se-toets,
    exercise/name = vraag,
    exercise/pre-hook = \SetExerciseProperty{section-title}{\secName},
    solution/pre-hook  = \noindent\bfseries{ Opgave \GetExerciseProperty{section-title}} \normalfont \\,
    }
\renewcommand*\theexercise{\arabic{exercise}.}

\newif\ifstudent
\DeclareExerciseTableTemplate{student*}{%
  \studenttrue
  \UseExerciseTemplate{table}{docent*}%
}
\DeclareExerciseTableTemplate{docent*}{%
  \XSIMputright\ExerciseTableCode{\hline Vraag & }%
  \ForEachUsedExerciseByType{\XSIMputright\ExerciseTableCode{#3&}}%
  \XSIMputright\ExerciseTableCode{ Totaal \\ \hline Type & }%
  \ForEachUsedExerciseByType{\XSIMputright\ExerciseTableCode{\ExercisePropertyGet{#1}{#2}{obit}&}}%
  \ifstudent\else
    \XSIMputright\ExerciseTableCode{ \\ \hline Niveau & }%
    \ForEachUsedExerciseByType{\XSIMputright\ExerciseTableCode{\ExercisePropertyGet{#1}{#2}{niveau}&}}%
  \fi
  \XSIMputright\ExerciseTableCode{ \\ \hline Punten & }%
  \ForEachUsedExerciseByType{\XSIMputright\ExerciseTableCode{\XSIMifblankTF{#5}{\printgoal{0}}{\printgoal{#5}}&}}%
  \XSIMputright\ExerciseTableCode{%
    \XSIMifblankTF{\ExerciseType}
      {\TotalExerciseGoal{points}{}{}}
      {\TotalExerciseTypeGoal{\ExerciseType}{points}{}{}}%
    \\ \hline
  }%
  \def\numberofcolumns{%
    \XSIMifblankTF{\ExerciseType}
      {\numberofusedexercises}
      {\csname numberof\ExerciseType s\endcsname}%
  }%
  \XSIMifeqF{\numberofcolumns}{0}{%
    \begin{center}
      \tiny
      \begin{tabular}{|l|*{\numberofcolumns}{c|}c|}
        \ExerciseTableCode
      \end{tabular}
    \end{center}%
  }%
}


\begin{document}

%=====================================
%   TOETS
%=====================================

\subsection*{Schoolexamen}

Het schoolexamen bestaat uit \numberofexercises vragen verdeeld over \total{section} opgaven. Er zijn \printtotalpoints punten te behalen.

%=====================================
%   OPGAVE
%=====================================

\lsection{Introductie: Juist of juist onjuist? \space {\normalfont \textit{\small naar: leerstof}}}
\vspace{-9pt}\hrule\vspace{15pt}

Bij deze opgave moet er een verklaring of uitleg gegeven worden waarom een stelling juist dan wel onjuist is. \textbf{Zonder} die verklaring of uitleg is het antwoord \textit{per definitie} \textbf{fout}! 

\begin{exercise}[points=2,obit=OB,niveau=H]
    De covalentie van koolstof is gelijk aan de covalentie van silicium.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
    \begin{itemize}[label={2 pt}]
    \item Juist, koolstof kan vier bindingen vormen met andere atomen. Silicium staat in dezelfde groep in het Periodiek Systeem en heeft een vergelijkbare atoombouw als koolstof. De covalentie van silicium is gelijk aan die van koolstof.
\end{itemize}

\end{solution}

\begin{exercise}[points=3,obit=IT,niveau=HV]
    In de stof salmiak \ch{NH4Cl} komt het ion \ch{NH4\pch[]} voor. Stikstof heeft in dit ion \ch{NH4\pch[]} dezelfde covalentie als koolstof in het molecuul \ch{CH4}.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
    \begin{itemize}[label={2 pt}]
    \item Juist. Zowel stikstof als koolstof hebben hetzelfde aantal waterstofatomen aan zich gebonden. Beide atomen hebben in deze verbindingen covalentie vier.
\end{itemize}
\end{solution}

%=====================================
%   OPGAVE
%=====================================

\lsection{Elektronen dansen in esters \space {\normalfont \textit{\small naar: leerstof en Binas}}}
\vspace{-9pt}\hrule\vspace{15pt}

De groepen \ch{-OH} en \ch{-NH2} worden functionele groepen genoemd. Ze bepalen mede hoe de moleculen waarin ze aanwezig zijn, zullen reageren met andere stoffen. Ethanol en ethaanamine lossen goed op in water. Ethaan lost niet in water op.

\begin{exercise}[points=2,obit=OB,niveau=H]
    Leg op microniveau uit waarom ethaan niet in water zal oplossen en ethanol en ethaanamine wel.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
    De functionele groepen in ethanol en ethaanamine bevatten polaire atoombindingen en zijn in staat om waterstofbruggen te vormen. Ethaan heeft alleen atoombindingen en kan geen waterstofbruggen met watermoleculen vormen.
    \begin{itemize}[label={1 pt}]
        \item benoemen verschil in polariteit van de atoombindingen in functionele groepen
        \item conclusie over de vorming van waterstofbruggen met water\textbf{moleculen}
    \end{itemize}
\end{solution}

Onderzoekers hebben achterhaald uit welke beginstof - ethanol of ethaanzuur - het zuurstofatoom tussen de beide C-ketens afkomstig is. Dat hebben ze gedaan door elk van de beginstoffen te labelen met het zuurstofisotoop \isotope{18,O}.

\begin{exercise}[points=2,obit=OB,niveau=H]
    Leg uit wat de verschillen zijn tussen het zuurstofisotoop \isotope{18,O} en een 'gewoon' zuurstofatoom.\\
    Maak hierbij gebruik van BINAS tabel 25A of ScienceData tabel <x>.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
    Verschil 1: Het zuurstofisotoop \isotope{18,O} verschilt in massagetal van het 'gewone' zuurstofatoom \isotope{O}, omdat het twee neutronen meer in de kern heeft.
    Verschil 2: 'Gewoon' zuurstof \isotope{O} komt meer dan 99\% in de natuur voor tegen \isotope{18,O} ongeveer 0,20\%.
    \begin{itemize}[label={1 pt}]
        \item \isotope{18,O} heeft twee neutronen meer in de kern / \isotope{18,O} heeft dus een groter massagetal
        \item \isotope{O} komt meer dan 99\% voor / \isotope{18,O} komt slechts 0,20\% in de natuur voor
    \end{itemize}
\end{solution}

\vfill
\flushright{\textbf{\large Einde van de toets}}\flushleft

\gradingtable[template=student*]

\pagebreak

%=====================================
%   CORRECTIE
%=====================================
\setcounter{page}{1}

\subsection*{Correctiemodel}

\printsolutions

\gradingtable[template=docent*]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @cgnieder .. your code works like a charm! I hadn't been using xsim for some time, but now I had to make new exams and tests, so I could really see how your code solved my question. Thanks again!